# Sphinx searcing related has_many with thinkingsphinx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

Hypothetically, I have a Room model that belongs to a Building model.  Buildings has a has_many relationship with categories.

I'm trying to figure out how to index the Room model so that a search for category_id = 1 will return any room, in any building that happens to have that category assigned to it.  Again, a building can have multiple categories.

thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, you'll want to set up your index something like the following in your Post model:

```
define_index do
  # fields go here

  # the important attribute for your filter:
  has building.categories(:id), :as => :category_ids
end
```

As for searching:

```
Room.search 'query', :with => {:category_ids => 1}
```

Let me know if this isn't quite what you're after.